How to compare secure boot keys stored in motherboard’s firmware database with the signed .efi files?
It’s a piece of cake to enable secure boot in a virtual machine, but I’m struggling to do the same with OpenSUSE on my 2012 vintage computer which refuses to boot in secure boot mode even in the standard configuration (with microsoft’s keys it seems).
I’d like to troubleshoot the most critical part: Do the keys match between the firmware and the shim ? How to check that ?

Have you cleared the keys? There should be a setting in the UEFI Firmware that will clear the currently loaded keys and reset them to default.  On that same screen I believe you can view the key.  See OpenSUSE: Secure Boot.  I believe you may also need the MOKManager

Yes, one of my attempts consisted to clear the keys and then set them to default. "Standard" mode is clearly shown for this configuration in UEFI. OpenSUSE uses shim.efi by default to implement secure boot so I believe that it is the only required file to be signed with microsoft keys. MokManager seems to deal with what comes next in the boot process and is not involved with UEFI but I may be wrong. What I’d like to check is the potential diferrence between those old microsoft keys in UEFI and the ones in the shim.

I also tried both microsoft keys and my own gerenated keys by sbctl, stripping the OpenSuse keys in shim, etc… I actually think that the implementation of secureboot is too primitive with this motherboard or simply broken in firmware updates.

You're Incorrect.  MokManager passes a signed key to the shim during the boot Process.  You need to add the default MS key provided by your MB manufacturer, i.e., the default key from Apple to MokManager and then tell it that that is the default key.  Also make sure SIP is turned off  I'll attempt to write up an answer shortly.  There's a lot of intertwined pieces to your puzzle.

What Is Secure Boot?
Quoting Particle.io:

...Secure Boot refers to the process of authenticating a device’s
firmware and operating system against a known secure cryptographic key
placed on the device at the time of manufacture. This authentication
occurs every time the device is booted to validate that the firmware
or code being loaded is the legitimate version that was placed there
by whoever produced it.

The quote above and the link refer to IoT devices.  The quote still holds true  with PC's if we consider them "things."  In the case of the OP's question it doesn't matter the age of the device as the premise of the quote was the same in 2012 as it is now.  I'm going to start the rest of this troubleshooting answer using the assumption that the key repository needs to be "reset", which the OP has already done, but I'm doing it for the benefit of future visitors.
Detailed Steps
Let's generate a numbered list of what we need to do to break this task into smaller chunks:

Read up on How Secure Boot works in Linux with regard to SuSE.  Note: The implementation in that link in 2012 is pretty much how all the distributions have implemented secure boot.

For simplicity sake I'm going to post the "meat" of that article (For those of you who skim read), as this is the foundational issue the OP is having):



Reset the Mac's Firmware to Factory Defaults by performing a PRAM Reset
Use these steps outlined by Roderick Smith

Step 3 may be simplified if the OpenSuSE Live ISO includes either the MokManager program or the MokUtil program.


Enroll your desired key into the MOK Database.

Optional: If you follow the above steps(Items 3 and 4) you will end up enrolling both the rEFInd key and the SuSE key.  If you plan on dual-booting OSX and OpenSuSE, I recommend this Boot Manger be used.  If you only plan on using OpenSuSE, you only need to enroll that certificate.


The shim should now be aware of the new keys and correctly pass the process to Grub2, and Grub 2 will boot OpenSuSE.

What to Do if the Above Steps Fail
See the Trobleshooting Section of Install openSUSE on a Mac.  As a hunch, quoting Roderick Smith again:

Some EFI implementations (mostly from before 2014) do a poor job of
honoring the boot options set via Linux's efibootmgr or other tools.
You may also lack access to such utilities, such as if you must
install rEFInd in Windows. In such cases, you may need to change the
boot loader's name so that the EFI will see it as the default boot
loader. rEFInd should then boot when your NVRAM lacks information on
specific boot loaders to use.

In the above case, rename OpenSuSE's shim<arch>.efi file to boot<arch>.efi, and place it in the BOOT directory(if there is no BOOT directory, place it in the root) where arch is either x32 or x64  If this method works, the OP's firmware only supports booting from one file. See: Alternate Naming Options.
On a side note, fixes like this are needed even on newer systems.  See: Update NVRAM so that shimx64.efi is run instead of grubx64.efi on Debian system for secure boot.  I feel the OP's pain in this regard.
